# Cómo ajustar el ancho de una cabecera de una tabla y ordenar las filas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, tablas

tengo el siguiente código para construir una tabla de resultados en Pyqt:

```
    def Tabla(self):
    #Boton de exportar a excel
    self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
    #self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 41, 31))
    icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd()+"\\images\\excel_tras.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

    self.toolButton.setIcon(icon1)
    self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
    self.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.exporta)
    self.toolButton.setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50)

    #Tabla
    self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    self.table.setObjectName("table")

    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.columnas))
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.listaDatos))

    #Colocamos la cabecera
    columna = 0
    for ele in self.columnas:
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(ele)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(columna, item)
        columna = columna + 1

    #Colocamos los datos
    fila = 0
    for lista in self.listaDatos:
        columna = 0
        for ele in lista:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(fila,columna, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(ele))
            columna = columna + 1
        fila = fila + 1

    #Layout
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 6, 0, 5, 7)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 5, 5, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
```

Y el aspecto de la tabla es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me gustaría que la última columna que se ve en la imagen se viese el texto completo ("Media uds vendidas últimos tres meses")

A mayores aprovecho la pregunta para ver si sabenalguna forma de que se pueda ordenar los valores de una columna de forma ascendente o descendente según se pulse sobre la cabecera.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de añadir la cabecera como una fila más, considera usar [`QTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setHorizontalHeaderLabels). Hecho esto puedes usar `QHeaderView.setSectionResizeMode` y especificar que se redimencione según el contendio mediante `QHeaderView.ResizeToContents`. Esto lo puedes aplicar sobre la cabecera de la columna que quieras especificando el índice  o a todas.

En cuanto a lo de ordenar las columnas, simplemente tienes que habilitarlo mediante el método `QTableWidget.setSortingEnabled()`, ahora bien, las columnas se ordenanan mediante orden lexicogŕafico. Si quieres que tus columnas que representan floats se ordenen como tales podrías crear una clase que derive de `QTableWidgetItem` y reimplementar adecuadamente el método `__lt__` (*rich comparison method*) usando para establecer el orden entre instancias de la clase.

A modo de ejemplo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets 



class CustomTableWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__ (self, value):
        super(CustomTableWidgetItem, self).__init__(str(value))

    def __lt__ (self, other):
        if (isinstance(other, CustomTableWidgetItem)):
            try:
                value  = float(self.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole))
                other_value = float(other.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole))
                return value < other_value
            except ValueError:
                pass
        return super().__lt__(other)


class Example(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.columnas = ["Familia", "PVP", "PUC", "Margen", "Stock",
                         "Media uds vendidas últimos tres meses"
                         ]
        self.listaDatos = [["Salsas y vinagres", 3.04, 2.29, 0.25, 11.0, 4.47],
                           ["Especias y sal", 1.22, 0.9, 0.26, 38.0, 30.33],
                           ["Platos Prep.", 2.7, 1.9, 0.3, 0.0, 0]
                          ]  
        self.tabla()        


    def tabla(self):
        #Tabla
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table.setObjectName("table")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.columnas))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.listaDatos))

        #Colocamos la cabecera
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.columnas)
        header_view = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        idx = header_view.count() - 1
        header_view.setSectionResizeMode(idx, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        #Colocamos los datos
        for fila, lista in enumerate(self.listaDatos):
            for columna, elemento in enumerate(lista):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(fila, columna,
                                         CustomTableWidgetItem(elemento)
                                         )
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True) 
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 6, 0, 5, 7)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Example()
    dialog.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra opción sería que usaras `QTableView` en vez de `QTableWidget` si nada te lo impide y `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Cuando necesites los índices de los elementos cuando iteras con un `for in`  usa `enumerate`, es más eficiente y simple que usar una variable.

Comment: Muy buen ejemplo! Muchas gracias!