# Como ordenar los datos de una columna en un QTableWidet

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas noches comunidad Stack.

Tengo la siguiente tabla y quiero saber si hay alguna manera de agregar filtros a las pestañas de por ejemplo ID, filtros como orden ascendente o descendiente:

¿Como puedo realizar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo:

```
from Firebase_load import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

def Mostrar(tabla):
    try:
        tabla.clearContents()
        tabla.setRowCount(0)
        ref  = db.reference('/Productos_Bar/')
        r0 = ref.get()

        for key in r0.values():
            _id = key.get('id')
            produc = key.get('producto')
            marca = key.get('marca')
            preci = key.get('precio')
            prec = '$ '+ (str(preci))
            x1 = str( key.get('exe1'))
            x2 = str(key.get('exe2'))
            x3 = str(key.get('exe3'))
            tabla.insertRow(tabla.rowCount())
            item1 = QTableWidgetItem(_id)
            item1.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item2 = QTableWidgetItem(produc)
            item2.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item3 = QTableWidgetItem(marca)
            item3.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item4 = QTableWidgetItem(prec)
            item4.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item5 = QTableWidgetItem(x1)
            item5.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item6 = QTableWidgetItem(x2)
            item6.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item7 = QTableWidgetItem(x3)
            item7.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            tabla.setItem(tabla.rowCount()-1,0,item1)
            tabla.setItem(tabla.rowCount()-1,1,item2)
            tabla.setItem(tabla.rowCount()-1,2,item3)
            tabla.setItem(tabla.rowCount()-1,3,item4)
            tabla.setItem(tabla.rowCount()-1,4,item5)
            tabla.setItem(tabla.rowCount()-1,5,item6)
            tabla.setItem(tabla.rowCount()-1,6,item7)
    except:
        QMessageBox.critical(None,"Error","undefined error \n\n Veirifique su conexión a internet             \t \n Reinicie el progrma \n Consulte soporte técnico ")
```

Comment: ¿Quieres ordenarlos tu previamente de acuerdo a ciertos parámtros o que el usuario pueda ordenar la tablas en función de una columna determinada? Mírate la segunda parte de esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/190058/15089 a ver si es eso lo que buscas.

Comment: ¿a qué te refieres con filtro?

Comment: @eyllanesc, como las funciones que tiene excel que ordena las columnas por orden alfabetico o sucesivo en el caso de los numeros

Comment: @Mystic_Force una cosa es el orden y otra es el filtro, ¿cual deseas?

Comment: @Mystic_Force si solo deseas orden debes usar de FJSevilla, es decir tienes que crear tus propios items